# What methods are available for comparing scripts between two databases?

Tags: .net, sql-server, deployment

I have two databases, a development and a live one. I have found that I am having trouble remembering to deploy all the updated stored procs to the live databases. What methods are recommended to deploy to a live database? Say, if the live database can be accessed through an RDP? My application is using sql server and .net (Visual Studio).

At the moment, I am just generating scripts and then doing a windiff on the folders.

Any thoughts will be useful.

Comment: If you have VS2013, you can check the differences with schema compare.

Comment: I have used SQL DBDiff tool in the past. It is really good and there is a free version. http://www.sqldbtools.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6:sqldbdiff-4-1&catid=8:sqldbdiff&Itemid=122